# jquery inputmask: masking curly braces

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask, input-mask

I want to wrap my user input with double curly braces, i.e. `sometext` -> `{{ sometext }}`. I have succeeded with wrapping the input using [Inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask), but cannot make it understant curly braces literally.

here is an example with wrapping the input with `%% double percentages %%`:

```
$('#masked').inputmask({
  mask: "%% a{1,20} %%"  
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vm2uu4xd/

But when I try to change the mask to `{{ a{1,20} }}` or `\{\{ a{1,20} \}\}` it breaks:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isGroup' of undefined
```

What is the proper format for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when I try to change the mask to `{{ a{1,20} }}` or `\{\{ a{1,20} \}\}` it breaks

Use double backslashes:

```
mask: "\\{\\{ a{1,20} \\}\\}"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vm2uu4xd/2/

Or define a different `ecsapeChar` yourself first - https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#escapechar